# Create an object with 3 headers : user,id,time

Tags: powershell

I want create an object with 3 headers : user,id,time .But it doesn't work: The 3 headers are in the elements of my object.

Here is my code:

```
$Table= @()

$table+="user,id,time"

$table+="1,2,3"


$t= $table | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        user = ($PSItem -split ',')[0]
        id = ($PSItem -split ',')[1]
        time = ($PSItem -split ',')[2]
      
    }
}

$t

Here is the output:
user id time
---- -- ----
user id time
1    2  3
```

I want this output:
user id time

---

1    2  3

what is the solution,please?

Comment: Just do `$table | Select-Object -Skip 1 |  ForEach-Object`

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input is in CSV format, so you can use [`ConvertFrom-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv?view=powershell-7.1) to turn it into object:

```
$Table= @()

$table+="user,id,time"

$table+="1,2,3"

$t = $table | ConvertFrom-CSV

$t
```

Output:

```
user id time
---- -- ----
1    2  3
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this method, but  the advantage with  the method "pscustomobject" is that I can change the type of the headers. with the method "ConvertFrom-CSV", I can't

Comment: @geekdu972 What do you mean exactly by "change the type of the headers"? Can you give an example?

Comment: [pscustomobject]@{
        [int]user = ($PSItem -split ',')[0]
        [string]id = ($PSItem -split ',')[1]
        [string]time = ($PSItem -split ',')[2]

Comment: @geekdu972 You can combine: `$table | convertfrom-csv | %{ [pscustomobject]@{ user = [int] $_.user; id = [string] $_.id; time = [string] $_.time } }`